# memory optimization с++

Tags: c++, string, optimization, memory, concatenation

How can I effectively merge two strings? I know only standard concatenation with "+" - str3 = str1 + str2, but this way is not memory-effective, because a new string is created every time.

Comment: fastest way might be to to use `+=` iirc `+=` resizes the string and copies the second at the end of first. `str1 += str2`

Answer (score 0):

There is [std::basic_stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) for that.

But if you only need to merge 2 strings, just [append](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) them.

Comment: `append ()` and `+=` are the same?

Comment: @KPCT they are certainly different things (function and operator), but one may be implemented by using another.

Comment: lol I know diff btw them, but internally aren't they the same. `+=`

Comment: @KPCT you are correct, the disassembly shows identical code, both are using   `std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Reallocate_grow_by<<lambda_ab246b20b9526e2ef7792587e4298a77>,char const *,unsigned int> (0401AA0h)`

Comment: Quoth the Standard: [Effects: Equivalent to: `return append(str);`](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.op.append#1)

Comment: @KPCT great, thank you for that link! However, `equivalent effect` is not `the same`, right?

Comment: No, It just means they have to do the exact same thing. How they get there is not formally defined. Probably A calls B, and when the compiler's done the intermediary call has been optimized out.

Comment: Here's GCC's take: `basic_string& operator+=(const basic_string& __str) { return this->append(__str); }`

Comment: @user4581301 right, as I commented above: `one may be implemented by using another`. Why the downvote?

Comment: Beats the fork out of me. I'll downvote at the drop of a hat, but I don't see anything wrong with your answer.

Comment: @VladFeinstein it was not me it was user4581301, but I remembered that I had this conversation few years back w someone.